# issue access hudson via remote web broswer

Tags: hudson

I am trying to access my Hudson page via another machine, Hudson IP is 192.168.24.2 IP of the machine I am trying to use to access Hudson is 192.168.24.15.  Hudson is using port 8080 on the localhost (24.2) I have no issues access it, but when i try remote host I get this error from my webpage.

"The server at 192.168.24.15 is taking too long to respond."

I hope someone can help point me in the right path.  As a side note i can ping the 24.2 server just fine, but cannot access the web.

I have Hudson running as a Linux service(not doing java - jar Hudson.war) in centos 6 trying to access in Firefox on a windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the port when accessing Hudson from other machines as well.  Try to get to Hudson using `http://192.168.24.15:8080`

Cheers!

Comment: What URL is working from the host machine?  When you use http://ip:port from the host (server running Hudson) does the site come up properly?  That should work unless it is contained in an additional server (ie: Jetty or Tomcat) you may need to append the product name, http://ip:port/hudson.

Comment: I am using hudson built in web service, and on the machine I have hudson installed on I can access it not problem form localhost:8080.  But when access it remotely as I said before I enter http://192.168.24.15:8080.  I just tried ip:port/hudson and it did not work and it took me to google.

Comment: If you can access Hudson from the localhost using port 8080 then we've confirmed that Hudson is up and working fine.  Which leads me to believe this is going to be a firewall on the machine hosting Hudson.

Comment: Thank you for the help,  I will check my iptables to see if it is blocking 8080 from going out.

Comment: The issue was my firewall was blocking port 8080 from going out.

Comment: Glad you found your issue and got things running!